# One particular SD card not working

Tags: ubuntu, sd-card, dmesg

I have a 32 GB SanDisk class 10 SDHC card. It works perfectly in my camera and in my netbook. However, when I plug it to my notebook I got this in dmesg:

```
[ 1824.729234] mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

I am sure that the SD card reader works because if I insert a microSD through a microSD to SD adaptor it works. I am using Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64 kernel 3.8.0-23-generic.